# Oracle 9i search and insert more data

Tags: oracle

[image]

Oracle 9i sql code

```
SELECT A.CSTNO, B.CSTNAME, A.YYYYMM
FROM table_A A, table_B B
WHERE A.CSTNO = B.CSTNO
AND YYYYMM = '201603'
```

I can get table_C view, but I want to get table_D

How can i do ?

oK i got it ~ thank you everyone

Comment: Can you please post your data in text format, not images? Besides, storing dates in text format may not be the best choice; can't you use `date` format or, if you don't want days, separate fields for year and month?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real answer, but too long for a comment.

It seems that you already get a result as in table_d:

```
SQL> select * from table_a;    
     CSTNO YYYYMM
---------- ------
    111111 201603
    222222 201603
    333333 201603
    444444 201603
    111111 201602
    222222 201602
    333333 201602
    999989 201603
    999999 201603

9 rows selected.

SQL> select * from table_b;   
     CSTNO CSTNAME
---------- ----------------
    111111 taipei
    222222 taichung
    333333 kaoshung
    999989
    999999

SQL> SELECT A.CSTNO, B.CSTNAME, A.YYYYMM
  2  FROM table_A A, table_B B
  3  WHERE A.CSTNO = B.CSTNO
  4  AND YYYYMM = '201603';

     CSTNO CSTNAME          YYYYMM
---------- ---------------- ------
    111111 taipei           201603
    222222 taichung         201603
    333333 kaoshung         201603
    999989                  201603
    999999                  201603

SQL>
```

So, if you need something like table_c, you need the following:

```
SQL> SELECT A.CSTNO, B.CSTNAME, A.YYYYMM
  2  FROM table_A A, table_B B
  3  WHERE A.CSTNO = B.CSTNO
  4    AND YYYYMM = '201603'
  5    AND B.CSTNAME IS NOT NULL;

     CSTNO CSTNAME          YYYYMM
---------- ---------------- ------
    111111 taipei           201603
    222222 taichung         201603
    333333 kaoshung         201603
```